# Will adding new generated column lock table in PostgreSQL 12

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

It is not clear from PostgreSQL documentation: will adding new generated column lock table?

I have big table in my PostgreSQL 12 installation and I need to execute SQL-patch:

```
ALTER TABLE abc ADD COLUMN gen TEXT GENERATED AS ALWAYS (...) STORED;
```

So, in my case it is unacceptable to lock whole table for long time. Is it safe to add new generated column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the generated column is `STORED`, PostgreSQL has to rewrite the table, so yes, this will take a long time.

Why don't you use a view to calculate the column on `SELECT`?

Comment: In my case I have a lot of READ queries and generating this column on the fly is not applicable (if using non-materialized views). I don't want use materialized views because of it's update complexity. 

Thx, I checked my table definition after adding generated column and made sure that Postgres adds default value for this column. Since this default value is not a literal so Postgres has to rewrite whole table